# Check if browser supports document.execCommand insertText

Tags: javascript, jquery

The only way what I found till now is  `document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')`, though it seems incorrect, for example this code not works in firefox, but above command returns `true`

```js
txt = "aaaaaaaaaaaa";
  
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log( document.queryCommandSupported('insertText') );
        $("#myinp").focus();
        document.execCommand("insertText", false, txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  id="myinp" ></textarea>
```

So, what is correct way for this?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility), it is supported in FF. Also, there's no need to create Fiddles for snippets you can create right here in your question.

Comment: Calling `document.designMode = "on";` first "fixes" this; however the text is inserted into the document, after the `<textarea>`. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/designMode, https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/b5y4ztp3/)

Answer (score 2):

`document.execCommand("insertText", false, txt)` returns `true`/`false`, so you can just use:

```js
if (document.execCommand("insertText", false, txt)) {
  // it worked
} else {
  // it didn't work
}
```

If you're looking for a cross-browser way to insert text, try [text-field-edit](https://github.com/fregante/text-field-edit). If you need IE8+ support, try the [insert-text-at-cursor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/insert-text-at-cursor) package. Both of them already run this check and have a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

The following demo will insert the text from the `<textarea>` at the bottom to the `contenteditable` `<fieldset>` at the top. `.execCommand()` needs to be within an event handler/callback function and it edits elements with the `[contenteditable]` attribute -- that could be any tag except form controls such as `<textarea>`, or `<input>`. The demo has `.execCommand()` within a `mouseup` event delegation.

---

### Demo

**Instructions**

- Type some text in the `<textarea>` at the bottom..
- Click anywhere or select any text within the `<fieldset>`.
- The text in the `<textarea>` will be inserted where the cursor is or where the text was selected within the `<fieldset>`

```js
$('.editor').on('mouseup', function() {
  var txt = $('.insert').val();
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, txt);
});
```

```html
<fieldset class="editor" contenteditable='true'></fieldset>
<textarea class='insert'style='min-width:98%'></textarea>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```